# Execute Celery's link_error callback on a separate queue/worker

Tags: python, celery

I have 2 apps on 2 separate servers, let's call them A and B. Both apps have a Celery worker active, listening to separate queues (QueueA and QueueB).

Server B pushes a task to QueueB, using `apply_async`.

Here is server B's tasks:

```
@app.task(bind=True, queue="QueueB", name="name_on_server_A")
def taskForServerB():
   # nothing is executed here

@app.task(bind=True)
def success(result):
   print('Task succeeded')

@app.task(bind=True):
def failure(...):
   print('task failed')


taskForServerB.s().apply_async(link=success.s(), link_error=failure.s())
```

On Server A, the task `name_on_server_A` receives the tasks and executes it. If it completes successfully, the task `success` is execute properly on ServerB, but it `name_on_server_A` fails, the task `failure` is not executed. Instead, Server A throws a `NotRegisteredError` for a task with name `failure`.

Is there something I am missing? How can I get the failure task to be executed on ServerB, where the first task is called from?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. The **route** of task to the correct queue which you defined for `name_on_server_A` (with the `queue` assignment) - which is by the way something that is new for me (I'm using ROUTER in the celery config and route each task by it's name to the right queue.
2. when you define your celery app you might forgot to include the task `failure` so it unregister:

   app = Celery(broker='amqp://', backend='...', include=['file1.py', 'file2.py', ..])